# Opening 2 audio-files and playing them simultaneously

Tags: java, javasound

Can I play 2 sound-files simultaneously?

I can handle the loading, changing loudness, opening and closing of one file.
How can I load 2 files in separate frames and start the playing with simultaneously hearing.

Comment: Please can you show us what you have done so far, and where do you struggle? Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to show us how you want to load and play the file. Are you able to play 1 sound file?

Answer (score 3):

Put the opening and the playing into two separate threads, then start them. The two threads can be synchronized so the playback starts synchronously.